# Frankfurt Transit Visa

Tags: transit-visas

I am travelling to my home country India from US. I have a change of flight in Frankfurt and my US visa has expired. Will I need transit visa? German Houston consulate told me I don't need one, but that was just verbal instruction. There is lot of conflicting views regarding this. Can anyone confirm there is not transit visa needed at Frankfurt airport?

Note: It might be thought as duplicate except that Houston German Consulate confirmed me that I don't need Transit visa unlike other answers indicate.

Comment: I don't see how the confirmation of the German Consulate changes anything of this being a duplicate. That answer should still be enough to answer your specific querry.

Comment: I think there's another exception to the airside TWOV rules, which isn't explained in the duplicated question. Under this exception, Indian travelers can transit through a couple of German airports, including FRA, can transit on the basis of an expired US visa if they are returning after having used the US visa. See [this Timatic search](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=IN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=IN&selDest=India&TR=DE&selTrans=Germany&user=OLYMPIC&subuser=OLYMPICB2C), but be sure to click through for the rules.

Comment: I believe it's this exception (see [this page from The German Missions](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Transit__Visa.html)) the OP would need to use to transit Frankfurt without a visa (assuming his itinerary satisfies all the requirements). Should we look at editing the canonical answer in the duplicated question to try to incorporate this?

Comment: I think point 4 in the duplicate touches on this but doesn't quite explain the details. I'd be in favor of someone editing the correct info into there (assuming someone understands it) and leaving this as a duplicate.

Comment: I tried to do just that. I relied somewhat heavily on the external link, because the rules are complicated and could be an entire answer themselves, but it should address the basic issue here, which is that the duplicate question basically claimed a visa was required, while an additional exception likely makes it unnecessary.

Comment: The existing answer does say that you won't need a visa (probably). See section 4, last para.